# Facebook integration with ASP.NET 4.0 Website(non MVC) - facebooksdk

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I am trying to integrate my asp.net 4.0(non MVC) website with facebook.

I want to retrive the authenticated user info.

The samples listed in facebooksdk is based on MVC. i tried to implement it in my website, but getting errors. i am struck.

If anyone implemented the facebook connect logic and retrieved the user information using facebook-c#-sdk, please help me how to do this.

I tried the same using facebooktoolkit, and i am able to retrive the user info. but the toolkit is having issues with .net 4.0.

Greatly appreciated your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some example code on how to protect a page called ProtectedPage.aspx and have a login page called LogOn.aspx:

Login.aspx:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2>
        Log In
    </h2>
    <p>
        <fb:login-button></fb:login-button>
    </p>
    <div id="fb-root">
    </div>
    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
    <script>
        FB.init({ appId: 'your app id', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.sessionChange', function (response) {
            if (response.session) {
                // A user has logged in, and a new cookie has been saved
                window.location.reload();
            } else {
                // The user has logged out, and the cookie has been cleared
            }
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

Login.aspx.cs

```
public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FacebookApp app = new FacebookApp();
            Authorizer authorizer = new Authorizer(app);
            if (authorizer.IsAuthorized())
            {
                Response.Redirect(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["returnUrl"] ?? "/"));
            }
        }
    }
```

ProtectedPage.aspx.cs

```
public partial class ProtectedPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FacebookApp app = new FacebookApp();
        Authorizer authorizer = new Authorizer(app);
        if (!authorizer.IsAuthorized())
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Account/Login.aspx?returnUrl=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.Url.PathAndQuery));
        }
    }
}
```

There are more samples and istructions on our [Codeplex wiki](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/documentation).

Comment: As far as I know when you access `Request.QueryString[]` it calls `UrlDecode` automatically.

Comment: fyi: This thread agrees that you dont need to manually `UrlDecode` items retrieved from `QueryString[]`: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t108005-request-querystring-and-server-urldecode.html

Comment: Thank you very much Nathan. I followed these steps and the work is done.

Comment: What is all this talk of a 'protected page'? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just Follow these simple steps:

- Use the official sdk: github.com/facebook/csharp-sdk .
- Implement the authentication process of your own.
- Read facebookk api documentation on web application authentication for better understanding the authentication process: developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#authenticating-users-in-a-web-application
- I have made an custom facebook classs for encapsulate this authentication process as much as possible. I have shared it on my blog on [facebook api authentication using c#](http://codesamplez.com/programming/facebook-api-access-token-using-c-sharp). You can use it as reference also.
- After getting the access token, all are straight forward. Just set the access token and call 'get' method for provate data.
- If you are still having problem,please let us know details.

Comment: How is this answer helpful? You could have just said 'read the instructions'.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good example of Facebook Auth 2.0 using facebook sdk from codeplex

[Facebook Auth 2.0 using facebook sdk](http://facebooksdk.blogspot.com/2011/03/facebookloginhelper.html)